# Why can I not PING when Subscribed using PUBSUB?

Tags: c#, azure, redis, servicestack.redis

I have an issue with using PUBSUB on Azure.

The Azure firewall will close connections that are idle for any length of time. The length of time is under much debate, but people think it is around 5 - 15 minutes.

I am using Redis as a Message Queue. To do this ServiceStack.Redis library provides a RedisMqServer which subscribes to the following channel:

```
mq:topic:in
```

On a background thread it blocks receiving data from a socket, waiting to receive a message from Redis. The problem is:

> If the socket waiting on a Redis message is idle for any length of time the Azure firewall 
>   closes the connection silently. My application is not aware as it is
>   now waiting on a closed connection (which as far as its concerned is
>   open). The background thread is effectively hung.

I had thought to implement some kind of Keep Alive which would be to wait for a message for  a minute, but if one is not received then PING the server with two goals:

1. Keep the connection open by telling Azure this connection is
   still being used.
2. Check if the connection has been closed, if so
   start over and resubscribe.

However when I implemented this I found that I cannot use the PING command whilst subscribed?? Not sure why this is, but does anyone have an alternative solution?

I do not want to unsubscribe and resubscribe regularly as I may miss messages.

I have read the following article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/02/14/connection-timeout-for-windows-azure-cloud-service-roles-web-worker.aspx which talks about how the Azure Load Balancer tears down connections after 4 minutes. But even if I can keep a connection alive I still need to achieve the second goal of restarting a subscription if the connection is killed for another reason (redis node goes down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just implemented PING support in Pub/Sub mode in the `unstable` branch of Redis in this commit: https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/27839e5ecb562d9b79e740e2e20f7a6db7270a66

This will be backported in the next days into Redis 2.8 stable.

Comment: Superb! I will add this ability to PING Redis clients during PUBSUB as a keep-alive ability into ServiceStack.Redis. I am using Azure hosted Redis as my server so I have no control over their version, but I will keep an eye and use this as soon as I can. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue due to our handling of keepAlive packets when hosting Redis in Azure.  We will have this fixed shortly.

Also, as suggested above you can keep the connection alive manually by pinging.  For a sub/pub connection a hack you can use today is calling unsubscribe to a random channel. (This is what StackExchange.Redis does)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mike. I've found that if I use the B2 (non replicated) offering the timeout issue is not as bad, but when I am using S1 (replicated, shared hardware) it is worse. Not sure if that is useful. I will consider adding that feature to my ServiceStack.Redis fork as hack for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

When a client subscribes, that connection is basically blocked for outgoing commands as it is used to listen for incoming messages. One possible workaround is to publish a periodic keepalive message on the channel.

Comment: What a coincidence - antirez has patched this today: https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/27839e5ecb562d9b79e740e2e20f7a6db7270a66 :)